# How to remove duplicates according to few fields

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this MySQL table ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61ccde/1)):

```
CREATE TABLE `units` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `location_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `square` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `units` VALUES 
(1,1,1500000,150.00,2010),
(2,1,2000000,150.70,2010),
(3,2,1800000,66.00,2013),
(4,3,3000000,75.00,2015),
(5,3,2400000,54.00,2015),
(6,4,1500000,78.50,2014),
(7,4,1400000,78.00,2014),
(8,4,1450000,79.00,2014),
(9,5,2600000,110.00,2017),
(10,6,2700000,124.00,2017);

id  location_id price   square  year
1   1           1500000 150     2010
2   1           2000000 150.7   2010
3   2           1800000 66      2013
4   3           3000000 75      2015
5   3           2400000 54      2015
6   4           1500000 78.5    2014
7   4           1400000 78      2014
8   4           1450000 79      2014
9   5           2600000 110     2017
10  6           2700000 124     2017
```

Now, I want to remove duplicates from each region with the same year where square differs between floor and round values, and get the minimum price in group. So, if we group `location_id = 1 and year = 2010`, then we should check if `square` in this group `between 150 and 151`, and select `ID` with `min(price)`.

The result I want to see is:

```
id
1
3
4
5
7
9
10
```

Is it possible to do with one query only? Any advices are welcome.

Comment: Why isn't `8` in the results? It has `square = 79`, which doesn't have the same floor as `78.5` and `78`.

Comment: Grouping has to be done by a function you calculate on each column (like `FLOOR(square)` or `ROUND(square)`), you can't easily do it by comparing rows with each other to see if they're close.